# Can I generalize this number theory result to finite chain rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I was working with $\mathbb{Z} \setminus p^m \mathbb{Z}$ and used the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^2 \equiv 0 \text{ mod p}.$$ Given an arbitrary finite chain ring $R$ with ideals $$\{ 0 \} = Rp^{m+1} < Rp^m < ... < Rp < R$$ and canonical homomorphism to $F = R \setminus Rp$: let $l = |F| = |Rp^m|$, $n = |Rp^{m-1}|$; is it true that $$l+ mn\sum_{i=1}^l f_i^2 \in Rp,$$ where each $f_i$ is a distinct element of $F$? If that doesn't work but there are similar results, I'd appreciate the information. I wasn't sure where to look for this one; thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's $R/Rp$. Yes, that canonical homomorphism. $|F|$ is not necessarily finite, and $|F| = |Rp^m|$ because in a finite chain ring, $|Rp^n/Rp^k| = |Rp^{m-(k-n)}|$. What do you mean by $p$ shouldn't be a prime element? And $m$ was factored out in the first one, but it had the analogous role. All these details aren't necessarily important; I guess I was just looking for general guidance of how to even approach this problem. Where do I find algebraic generalizations of number-theoretic results?

Answer (score 1):

I found it; I was basically looking for something along these lines:

Let F be a finite field with q elements.  Let m be a positive integer. Then

$\sum_{a \in F} a^m = 0$ unless $(q-1)$ divides $m$.

$\sum_{a \in F} a^m = -1$ if $(q-1)$ divides $m$.

So the sum of all finite field elements squared is $0$ except when $q = 2,3$.
Thus, we can find an element in $F$ such that the desired equation is true.
Sorry about not providing enough details; it would have taken a while to explain.

Comment: And where is the "chain ring" hidden in this answer?

Comment: Well the answer happened to be general enough that it didn't need to make any reference to chain rings; it applied to all finite fields. There's no contradiction here.